# Abstracting/Creating a general update function ajax ready made

Tags: php

I am trying to abstract the update query into a function so I can implement it easier into some ajax calls. But I am trying for about 2 hours and can't get it to start (brain is boiling).

```
public function update_table_multi($table_name, array $col_names, 
                array $sets, $where_name, array $wheres) {

}
```

How it should work

Table:

```
 ID     banner              bannercode                      location        status
  3     Pagerank buttons    Pagerank buttons banner code    pagerank-buttons    0
  5     Index buttons       Index banner codes              index-buttons       0

$cf->update_table_multi('advertising', array('banner', 'bannercode'),
                array($_POST['array_bnames'], $_POST['array_bcodes']), 'ID', 
                $_POST['array_values']);
```

I managed to do 1 function like this just that accepts only one column to be updated:

```
public function update_table_where($table_name, $col, $where_col, array $keys, array $values) {
    $data_array = array_combine($keys, $values);
    foreach($data_array as $where_val=>$set_val) {
        $this->db->query("UPDATE $table_name SET $col = '$set_val' WHERE $where_col = '$where_val'");
    }
    echo "Data had been updated";
}
```

And it's used like this:

```
update_table_where('table_name', 'column1_name', 'where_column_name', array of values received from ajax reading column1_name);
```

Comment: This is possible, but it is very bad architecture. It forwards the complexity and power of SQL to the front page, thus tearing down borders between separate layers of an application. That is a very bad idea.

Comment: @arkascha I understood that is better to use PHP than sql, php processor is much faster than sql.

Comment: are you using any framework?

Comment: @ShaunakShukla No framework trying to abstract myself in my way the update query.

Comment: ok, update_table_multi function is in Model class, right? If you are using MVC based coding structure..

Comment: @ShaunakShukla nope a simple function.

Comment: !! If you're doing AJAX call, then It would be good that you add javascript portion here.. and Ajax doesn't call any php function, it calls URL, and URL manipulates page or function that work as page...

Comment: @ShaunakShukla, I know but that is not important, important is what it receives, and I explained it with intuitive indexes and variables. array_bnames = array('value1', 'value2'); array_bocodes same type of array as array_banames. array_values = array(1, 2) { the id's of the rows.}

Comment: "php is much fasteer than sql" is utter nonsense. They serve completely different purposes and run inside completely different environments. You cannot compare them.